# Using an if statement to join two data frames together

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:

```
> df1
  match1        match2 someData
1   AAPL         Apple      100
2   GOOG    Google Inc      105
3   MSFT Microsoft Inc      103
4   <NA>        Nvidia       99
5   <NA>        Amazon      101
6   INTC         Intel       98
> df2
   toMatch1   toMatch2 someOtherData
1      AAPL      Apple          1000
2      INTC      Intel           500
3      MSFT  Microsoft           750
4      GOOG     Google          1250
5       MMM         3M          1500
6      ATVI Activision          1000
7      AMZN     Amazon          1750
8      NVDA     Nvidia          2000
9      TSLA      Tesla           500
10       FB   Facebook           250
```

I want to join them together using an `if` statement. In the `df1` data, under the column `match1` there are `NA` values for two observations. I would like to create the `if` statement such that:

> if column exists in `match1` join `match1` with `toMatch1` using an "exact match" `left_join`
>
> else join using `match2` with column `toMatch2` using a "fuzzy match" `stringdist_join`

I can join using:

```
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("match1" = "toMatch1"))
stringdist_join(df1, df2, by = c("match2" = "toMatch2"))
```

However when I use the second approach I obtain:

```
> stringdist_join(df1, df2, by = c("match2" = "toMatch2"))
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  match1 match2 someData toMatch1 toMatch2 someOtherData
  <fct>  <fct>     <dbl> <fct>    <fct>            <dbl>
1 AAPL   Apple       100 AAPL     Apple             1000
2 NA     Nvidia       99 NVDA     Nvidia            2000
3 NA     Amazon      101 AMZN     Amazon            1750
4 INTC   Intel        98 INTC     Intel              500
```

But `Google Inc` in `df1` should have been joined up with `Google` in `df2` and it hasn't. The same for `Microsoft Inc` and `Microsoft`. It seems that the `stringdist_join` function is only looking for "exact matches" also...

My question is, I want to create an `if` statement to first look at the `match1` and `toMatch1` columns and if there are values in these columns join the data on an exact match. Otherwise look at the `match2` and `toMatch2` column and try to join the data using `fuzzyjoin`.

Data:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(
  match1 = c("AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT", NA, NA, "INTC"),
  match2 = c("Apple", "Google Inc", "Microsoft Inc", "Nvidia", "Amazon", "Intel"),
  someData = c(100, 105, 103, 99, 101, 98)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  toMatch1 = c("AAPL", "INTC", "MSFT", "GOOG", "MMM", "ATVI", "AMZN", "NVDA", "TSLA", "FB"),
  toMatch2 = c("Apple", "Intel", "Microsoft", "Google", "3M", "Activision", "Amazon", "Nvidia", "Tesla", "Facebook"),
  someOtherData = c(1000, 500, 750, 1250, 1500, 1000, 1750, 2000, 500, 250)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust the `max_dist` parameter in `stringdist_join`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
ans1 <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("match1" = "toMatch1"))
ans2 <- stringdist_join(df1, df2, by = c("match2" = "toMatch2"), max_dist  = 4)
ans2

# A tibble: 10 x 6
#   match1 match2        someData toMatch1 toMatch2  someOtherData
#   <chr>  <chr>            <dbl> <chr>    <chr>             <dbl>
# 1 AAPL   Apple              100 AAPL     Apple              1000
# 2 AAPL   Apple              100 INTC     Intel               500
# 3 AAPL   Apple              100 GOOG     Google             1250
# 4 AAPL   Apple              100 TSLA     Tesla               500
# 5 GOOG   Google Inc         105 GOOG     Google             1250
# 6 MSFT   Microsoft Inc      103 MSFT     Microsoft           750
# 7 NA     Nvidia              99 NVDA     Nvidia             2000
# 8 NA     Amazon             101 AMZN     Amazon             1750
# 9 INTC   Intel               98 AAPL     Apple              1000
#10 INTC   Intel               98 INTC     Intel               500
```

To give preference to `ans1` you can then use `anti_join` to remove `match1` values in `ans2` which are already present in `ans1`.